# What are the requirements of a men's mikva?

Tags: halacha, minhag, men-male, mikvah-ritual-bath

There are many requirements given for a women's mikvah (See Yoreh De'ah siman 201), yet I have not seen much information regarding a men's mikva (to tovel every day before prayers or for Erev Yom Kippur).

What are its minimum requirements?

1. Can one Tovel in a Keili (according to one Shitta in Gemara Brachos one can. Does Halacha/General practice follow that opinion)?
2. Can one Tovel when the filter is on?
3. Is one allowed to tovel in zochelin (moving waters)?
4. Is one allowed to tovel in snow?

Comment: [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) 1-4 as separate questions please.

Answer (score 4):

According to Berachos 22a-b, the minimum volume of water required to cleanse a [Baal Keri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keri) is 9 kabs of water thrown on him, however it is preferable to use a Mikveh. In a Mikveh, full-body-immursion is required without being in contact with the walls. Eiruvin 4b says that the minimum volume for this is 1 ama x 1 ama x 3 amas high, or 40 seah.

R. Akiva and Juda Glostera add at the bottom of Berachos 22a that 9 kabs is just for someone who is both sick and has involuntary emissions. However Rashi says that Talmedi Chachamim are always a little sick, and can therefore use 9 kabs. Rav Dovid Grossman, in the iTalmud app shiur, says he saw a Shevet Halevi which says showering for a few minutes would be enough since the 9 kabs of water doesn't have to come from a Keili or have human force behind it.

Rav Grossman, says we hold like Takanas Ezera that in a Mikveh, a Baal Keri is cleansed even if his Mikveh is Keili and he has a Chatziza.

And CYLOR.

Answer (score -5):

Men also immerse in a mikveh before Aliyah la-Regel thrice annually, to ascend the Temple Mount, or for kohanim to eat their terumah. The mikveh must not be pasul, and men who are immersing inside of it should worry about devarim she-chotzetzim. But ddaily *tevilah* as well as Yom ha-Kippurim tevilah is just as important as these other ones.

Comment: So your answer to "what are the requirements" is: it should not be pasul?

Comment: it's the same kind of mikveh...

Comment: As the question was about toveling as a matter of minhag (and not the required times you mention) you should source your statement that toveling as minhag requires a as kosher a mikveh as would be required by a niddah.

Comment: A Mikva for Aliya Leregel (or for Truma) must be a kosher mikva since it is required de'oraisa (like a Nidda). Going on Erev Yom Kippur (or every morning) is only a Minhag, so different laws apply (for example, one can use 9 kavim which one cannot use instead of a normal mikva if one needs to be Tahor to eat Teruma)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - Minhag Yisrael Torah Hee?

Comment: It says (in the Gemara and IIRC the Shulchan Aruch) that one can use Tisha Kavim by Erev Yom Kippur which one cannot use for Truma

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - Well, look at the Gemara there in Brachot chpt. 3, it says that you should try to avoid the 9kav and do the whole thing. And, they whispered that you don't even have to do it whatsoever.