# Can you use a pool for a mens mikvah

Tags: halacha, chasidut-hasidism, mikvah-ritual-bath, men-male, swimming

Is a pool allowed to be used as a mikvah for keri, for erev shabbos, and Shabbos 
day? If so does the filter have to be off? Since it is not only made of rain water i am having a doubt. Please answer in a chabad or chassidic point of view.

Comment: Why would you think you can or can't?

Comment: Because it does not only have rain water.

Comment: Which of my questions were you answering? (Don't answer here, but rather [Edit] your question to include your thought process, what you have checked already, etc. Doing so will help others best help you.)

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22501&st=&pgnum=70

Comment: http://www.dinonline.org/2010/06/29/using-pool-as-mikva/

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17134/759

Comment: A Breslov Chassid with Semicha (who really knew his stuff) that worked with my dad used our swimming pool as a Mikvah when he was unable to get to the men's mikvah before Yom Tov. It is not optimal, but it does the job.

Comment: Igros Moshe [vol. 2 _Yoreh De'a_ #110](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14674&st=&pgnum=199) is against it for several reasons on the basis of Ramba"m's opinion (which is preferred by the Sha"ch), but explains and doesn't hold of a conflicting opinion (unclear to me exactly whom he's referring to) that would allow it with the filter off (in case even a small amount of turnover constitutes _z'chila_). He cites his own longer treatment of the issue in _Dibros Moshe_ 44:3.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara writes in [Brachos](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=22b&format=text)

> ת"ר בעל קרי שנתנו עליו ט' קבין מים טהור בד"א לעצמו אבל לאחרים ארבעים סאה ר' יהודה אומר מ' סאה מכל מקום ר' יוחנן וריב"ל ור"א ור' יוסי בר' חנינא חד מהאי זוגא וחד מהאי זוגא ארישא חד אמר הא דאמרת במה דברים אמורים לעצמו אבל לאחרים מ' סאה לא שנו אלא לחולה המרגיל אבל לחולה לאונסו ט' קבין וחד אמר כל לאחרים אפילו חולה לאונסו עד דאיכא מ' סאה וחד מהאי זוגא וחד מהאי זוגא אסיפא חד אמר הא דאמר רבי יהודה מ' סאה מכל מקום לא שנו אלא בקרקע אבל בכלים לא וחד אמר אפי' בכלים נמי בשלמא למ"ד אפי' בכלים היינו דקתני ר' יהודה אומר מ' סאה מכל מקום אלא למ"ד בקרקע אין בכלים לא מכל מקום לאתויי מאי לאתויי מים שאובין
>
> The rabbis learned in a baraissa: A baal keri who had 9 kav of 
>   water poured on him is Tahor. when are these words said? 
>    (when he wants to daven or learn) for himself. But (if he 
>   wants to daven or learn) for others, 40 seah is required. Rabbi 
>   Yehuda said that 40 seah is always required. Rabbi Yochanon 
>   and Rabbi Yehoshua Ben Levi, and Rabbi Elazar and Rabbi 
>   Yosi Ben Rabbi Chanina: one of this pair and one of that pair 
>   argue concerning the first part of the baraissa. One of them 
>   said: Where the baraissa qualifies “when are these words 
>   said? for himself, but for others, 40 seah is required,” that is 
>   referring to a sick person who has regular marital relations, but 
>   for a sick person who sees keri accidentally, only 9 kav is 
>   required, and one of them said: for others, even a sick person 
>   who sees keri accidentally, it is not sufficient unless there is 40 
>   seah. And one from this pair and one from that pair argue 
>   concerning the last part of the baraissa. One of them said that 
>   that which Rabbi Yehuda says that 40 seah is always required 
>   is only where the water is in the ground, but if the water is in a 
>   vessel, it will not work. And the other one said that it works even in a vessel. According to the one who says that 40 seah 
>   works even in a vessel, it makes sense that Rabbi Yehuda 
>   learned 40 seah is always required, but according to the one 
>   who said taht 40 seah works only in the grand but not in a 
>   vessel, what does Rabbi Yehuda add by saying ‘always.’ He 
>   means to include drawn water.

From the end of the Braisa, we see that Rabbi Yehuda says that drawn water is fine for Tevilas Ezra.

R' Shneur Zalman of Liadi ([Orach Chaim 88:1](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/7/88/1)) codifies this:

> ותשעה קבין אלו אינן מטהרין אלא כששופכין עליו אבל לא כשטובל בהם בין שהם בכלי בין בקרקע עד שיהיה ארבעים סאה (בקרקע) ואז מועילים לטבול בהם אפילו לבריא ששמש מטתו אפילו הם שאובים
>   These nine Kav only purify when they are poured, but not when one dips in them, unless there are forty Seah in the ground. [Once there are these forty Seah], even a healthy person who had relations may dip in them even if [the water] is drawn.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What does the Alter Rebbe mean by healthy relations and 40 seah in the ground?

Comment: @DovidBenizri They can't (according to some opinions) rely on 9 kavim, and the water can't be in Keilim.

Comment: What about Zochalin?

Comment: @DoubleAA turn off the filter

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Is that really necessary? It's a closed system

Comment: @DoubleAA: Is Zochalin a psul deorayta?

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom For a Mikva, I think so.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Is there a way to turn off the filter to avoid the zochalin issue? I have no idea how pools work.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom Probably every pool is different.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom What are you trying to use a pool for that you need it to be Kosher DeOrayta? Tevilat Keilim?

Answer (score 0):

For Keri a pool can be good enough since it satisfies the Takkanas Ezra, as mentioned above. For Hosafas Kedusha you would need a real Mikva.

It is possible to make a pool Kosher. If you allow at least 20 Sa'ah of rainwater to collect before adding the rest, and if the faucet is higher up -- causing the water to flow along the bottom before reaching the rest -- it can be Kosher.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Benny. Your answer would be much more useful if you provided some sources.

Comment: *For Hosafas Kedusha you would need a real Mikva.* How do you know that?

Comment: Moreover, the [Alter Rebbe](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/sh/sh4/3/607) implies that one doesn't need a kosher mikva for Teshuva. I don't see why Hosafas Kedusha would be stricter.

Comment: Rebbe Chaim Vittal writes that the Arizal's mother didn't let him immerse in the winter since he wasn't well. Why couldn't he just wash in heated water? Likewise, it says to wash Erev Shabbos in warm water and then to immerse.

Comment: Perhaps the pool is better than nothing. A big difference between Takanass Ezra and Hosafas Kedusha is that in the case of the former you are being Yotzei something. There is no point in doing more. Just like tog can't not cross a street better. However, for Ruach Tahara you want to do more for more Tahara.

Comment: Tevila BeMerchatzaos?

Answer (score -1):

For normal mikva (daily/erev Shabbos/shabbos) if you don't have anything else, you can use it, and it's better to have the filter off being that it's not mandatory from the Torah. As for mikva that is mandatory  it needs a proper mikva. If you don't have one, maybe you should go to a pool in the mean time (not so sure), but it won't make you Tahor. Just to point out, in Camp Gan Yisroel around the world, if there's no lake or mikva, people use a pool.

Comment: Thank you. It is good to hear an answer from a lubavitcher chossid like me. But why keri no?

Comment: As I recall hearing and learning a shower is bedieved more than enough for keri (See here for example, I randomly pulled it up from google: http://dafyummy.blogspot.com/2012/08/berachot-22a-how-long-is-9-kav-shower.html. ) A mikvah is maybe a chumrah if needed, and serves other purposes too. Mens mikvahs arent even fully kosher for a nidah in most cases...

Comment: @DovidBenizri I took out the mention of keri from my answer, I asked someone and they said that there was a gezeira that he needs to go to mikva which was abolished, but ask a Rov if you need to know for sure. I was initially under the incorrect impression that mikva for a keri is mid'oraysa

Answer (score -1):

From DailyHalacha.com (a sephardic website): http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1215

A woman who is a Nidda can divest herself of this status only by immersing in a Halachically valid Mikveh, which is defined as 40 Se'a of naturally collected rainwater, that had not been drawn from another source. This means that a Mikveh must be constructed in such a way that rainwater falls directly into the Mikveh. If the water is brought to the Mikveh from somewhere else, either through human involvement or a piping system, it is invalid, and a Nidda who immerses in such a Mikveh is still considered a Nidda.

For this reason, Chacham Ovadia Yosef rules (in Halichot Olam, vol. 5, p. 143) that a swimming pool may not be used as a Mikveh. The water in a swimming pool has the status of Mayim She'uvim – "drawn water" – and is therefore ineffective in ridding a woman of her Nidda status.

When Chacham Baruch Ben Chaim Z”L served as Rabbi in Salsbury, South Africa, he sent a letter to Chacham Ovadia Yosef asking if he could permit the women in his community to immerse in swimming pools, given that no proper Mikveh was available. He noted that if he would not permit women to immerse in swimming pools, they would resume relations with their husbands without immersing altogether. Since pools are disqualified for use as a Mikveh only Mi'de'rabbanan (by force of Rabbinic enactment), perhaps it is preferable to instruct women to violate this provision, and immerse in pools, so as to avoid their violation of the far more grievous transgression, of relations during a state of Nidda.

Chacham Ovadia replied that a Rabbi may not allow people to commit a Rabbinic prohibition even in such a case, where they will otherwise violate a Torah prohibition. Halacha does not become more flexible in response to the "intimidation" of those who are prepared to transgress Torah law if a Rabbinic provision is not suspended. This principle is explicitly mentioned as well by Rabbi Moshe Feinstein (Russia-New York, 1895-1986), in his work Iggerot Moshe (Yoreh Dei'a section, 52; listen to audio for direct citation), where he writes that a Rabbi may not allow a violation of Halacha of any kind due to the threats of sinners that they will otherwise commit more grievous transgressions.

Chacham Ovadia added another factor, as well, namely, that issuing a ruling permitting the use of pools as a Mikveh eliminates any incentive on the part of the community to construct a proper Mikveh. For this reason, too, a Rabbi must not issue such a ruling, and should rather insist that the community take it upon itself to construct a valid Mikveh.

Summary: A swimming pool may not be used in lieu of a Mikveh, even if no proper Mikveh is available.

Comment: This is good in that it quotes one late rabbis opinion, but it provides no reasoning or sources to a complex and non-trivial question.

Comment: It also talks about womens' mikvas, while the question was about mens'.

Comment: It talks about women's use of a Mikva. Mikva's don't have genders.

Comment: +1 doubleAA, the context is about woman, but kal ve chomer to man

Comment: @user5523 I don't know what the Kal and Homer is. Both have the exact same requirement AFAICT.

Comment: @DoubleAA are you joking - nidda needs a mikva, (zov needs maim chaim), ball kery ok in sheuvim but not in a kli see [mogain avrochom 88.1 5th line and mhatis hashekel there 2nd line](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x454)

Comment: @shmuel It must be you who is telling the joke as that source is just about reading Shema according to a now-nullified enactment.

Comment: @DoubleAA What is the source that he is like a woman?

Comment: @shmuel He's not "like a women". [Anyone impure, whether human or vessel, whether impure with strict impurity or rabbinic impurity, does not become pure until they dip in a Mikva.](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=10&hilchos=63&hilite=) This is a pretty basic rule of Tahara.

Comment: @DoubleAA this halocho excludes a zaav why should it not also exclude a baal keri

Comment: @shmuel Are you serious? Zav is special as noted later in [Halacha 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=11353) but everyone else is fine in a regular Mikvah.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes it is fine but according to some opinions not needed see [bais yosef 159.16](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x772) or [taz 159.20](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x961)

Comment: @shmuel You think those opinions are referring to Tumah??? That's practically unfathomable. The Raavad is speaking about reading Shema according to a now-nullified enactment, as we discussed earlier.

Comment: @DoubleAA how about [mishnah mikvaot 8.1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37951&st=&pgnum=107)

Comment: @shmuel Same thing. See Rambam and Bartenura. Rashash there suggests it's talking about certain kinds of Keri-Derabanan, but even he agrees that regular Keri (from regular ejaculation) needs a real Mikvah.

Comment: @DoubleAA you are right I am wrong.  But what is the source that we care for tuma today (excluding going to har habais) ps thank you for your patients

Comment: @shmuel We care about Tumah as much as ever: if you want to be Tahor do so and if you want to be Tamei do so. That's no different than back in the day. (Agav, another reason besides going on Har HaBayit that might prompt someone to want to be Tahor is wanting to eat Challat Chu"l.)

Comment: @DoubleAA where/what can i read about this, that even though we are tumat met we can still worry about tuma?, should we not have to go to a maayan just in case?

Comment: @hazoriz I don't understand your question, nor why you are bringing maayan into this.

Comment: @DoubleAA you wrote "We care about Tumah as much as ever" where can i read about this... i was told in the name of a Rav that now we are all bheskat tomai zaav

Comment: @hazoriz ??? I am not a Zav, AFAIK. I guess you can read about it in the Rambam's 9th Ikar? I don't know what else to tell you. Of course Torah still applies.

Answer (score -2):

It really depends on why one is using the Mikvah, and "Men's Mikvah" doesn't help (other than to eliminate Nidah). For many, it is simply because there is an 'Inyan' and Mitzvas Anashim M'lumadah. In the absence of any clear reason why one is doing it, it would be very hard to pin down what Mikvah is acceptable. Specifically, without being very welled versed in Hilchos Mikvaos *and* clearly understanding the reason, it is impossible to evaluate what leniencies can be relied upon in defining a Kosher Mikvah.

Here are several possible reasons why a Mikvah may be used, and their implications in regards to a pool.

1. [For Nidah & Geirus most pools are probably useless for a variety of reasons.]
2. For Tevilas Ezrah (Keri), even a shower of Tisha Kavim Mayim She'uvim (9 kav-units of drawn water) is generally agreed to be enough (for example, see [here Answer 1](http://www.techques.com/question/27-17134/What-are-the-requirements-of-a-men's-mikva) or [here](http://dafyummy.blogspot.com/2012/08/berachot-22a-how-long-is-9-kav-shower.html)). There is a chumrah to use a mikvah to adhere to other views on this matter, and Kabalah. Therefore it would seem that one could use a pool, though maybe not if one wanted to adhere to *all* the views.
3. There is an often cited reason from I-forget-who that if a Mikvah can make someone a yid, how much more can it elevate someone who is already a yid. To fulfill this, one probably can't use a pool, unless this reason is more symbolic than anything else.
4. It removes certain types of Tumah. Therefore nowadays, when we are all Tamei Meis, it won't help even if/when it is Kosher.
5. A Sofer should use it in general and specifically before writing Hashem's name (It is not clear in Halacha the level of Chiyuv; at any rate it doesn't Pasel his Kesivah if he didn't.) Everyone should before the Days of Judgement (Rosh Hashanah & Yom Kippur). Many other reasons to use a Mikvah are given based on Kabalah, in many Seforim and by many Gedolim, predominately amongst Chasidim (and Sefardim?). But for all these, clear rules are hard to come by. One would need to know (1) which Sefer/Gadol one was attempting to adhere to *and* clearly understand their reasoning, and (2) Hilchos Mikvaos inside out, only then making an informed decision about what leniencies are acceptable.

Comment: Tumat Keri and Tumat Niddah need the same kind of Mikva AFAIK.

Comment: Don't know why you are convinced it's not valid for a Niddah. There are Poskim on both sides.

Comment: From what I recall, hearing from people building mikvahs - There may (likely) be an issue with even a tiny leak, they test with straws on the surface etc, you would have to test your pool. Also, there would be an issue with Mayim sheuvim, unless done properly. There are probably more, I just don't know the halachos well enough, but I recall that there are an amazing amount of problems that crop up with Mikvaos for Nidos.

Comment: As far as them both needing the same mikvah, I know a shower doesn't work for Nidah, and I know that *many* say a shower will be enough for keri - halachicly, nine kav mayim are enough (maybe not *tumas* baal keri, but then we are already tamei meis...)

Comment: Most pools are probably not filled with Sheuvim unless you know otherwise (piping probably doesn't matter if it's designed to be attached to the ground). And Tumat Keri is more restrictive that Tumat Meit and is sometimes worth getting rid of on its own.

Comment: @DoubleAA <(piping probably doesn't matter if it's designed to be attached to the ground)> It's a Machlokes HaPoskim

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Is it? Shulchan Arukh and Rama seem pretty clear http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.9E.D7.97

Comment: @DoubleAA "And Tumat Keri is more restrictive..." What is the source for this? I am aware of one discussion where keri and another Tumah coincide, the Mishnah in Brachos 3-6, but that again is for Tevilas Ezrah, not Tumah. For Tumah I believe it is superseded in every way by Tumas Meis, and unremoveable in its presence (hence it can't be gotten 'rid of on its own').

Comment: @Jeff Try Keilim 1:8 to start.

Comment: @DoubleAA I stand corrected about it being less restrictive, as in you example of Shiluach Machaneh, thank you. Is there a source that Tevilah would remove this restriction if one is already Tameh Meis?

Comment: @Jeff I don't know that I'll find an explicit early source for that as it seems quite obvious. We know Niddah/Zavah/Yoledet can be removed; why not Keri/Zav?